# Icon image cutting off in tab navigator - react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

Using react-navigations - createBottomTabNavigator, im trying to push the icons down a bit but its getting cut off and im not sure as to why.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this by any chance? or if you could direct me to some info about this.

The icon style is below:

```
<Icon
   name="heart"
   color={tintColor}
   size={28}
   style={{ marginTop: '20' }}
 />
```

And heres the tab bar options:

```
 tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    indicatorStyle: {
        height: 100
    },
    style: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        height: 50,
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.94,
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 33,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 33,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        bottom: 0,
        margin: 10,
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 0.3
        },
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowOpacity: 0.1

    },

    tabStyle: {}
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: View’s height is not enough to show images entirely. You can add a background color something like red to styles and check whether that view height is the issue here. Or simply use react native inspector to inspect element details

Comment: thanks @SamithaNanayakkara, yeah, looks like it cutting off from the button, how would i set the view height? Should this be set at the icon level? many thanks!

Comment: Actualyl got it :) thanks !!!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for Samitha, had to set the icon height:

```
<Icon
    name="heart"
    color={tintColor}
    size={28}
    style={{ marginTop: 30 , height: 28 }}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

The bottom of the iPhone X is reserved for the home swipe bar

react-navigation like allot of other libraries implement the new [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview) or add their own padding to the bottom of the iPhone X to stop you from putting content in that zone.

It's unlikely your buttons will work properly if placed that low so there's not much you can do here.